# Send SMS using API in php url not responding

Tags: php, api, post, get, sms

```
$data ='username=' .$username . '&api_password=' . $hash . '&sender=' . $sender . "&to=" . $numbers . "&message=" . $message . "&priority=11" ;


// Send the GET request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://****************' . $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process your response here
echo $response;
```

I can send sms using this php code from localhost. But when i upload this code to server I cannot get a respose from the url.

```
$data = array('username' => $username, 'api_password' => $hash, "sender" => $sender, 'to' => $numbers, "message" => $message, "priority" => 11);


// Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://**********************');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process your response here
echo $response;
```

I also tried this method. I can send sms from my localhost. But no response when i upload this on  my live server. is there any other method to send sms in php?
 Please Help !!!

Comment: what is the error , is curl installed on your server see access and error logs

Comment: check `http_code`. In SMS system they send http_code for success, failure or bounce etc.

Comment: @ M A SIDDIQUI  There is no error showing. the url not responding. How can i install curl on server?

Comment: what php version is being used on your live server?

Comment: @Akin PHP version 5.4

Comment: have you checked your error logs? You should find something wrong there. Also, turn on error_reporting in your dev environment. Really helps

Comment: @Akin I am using this code in android. I am getting no response. when i call this page from android. I am new to programming. dont know much about android and php.

Comment: Check your root directory i think, you should have a file called error_log if its cpanel. But clarify from your hosting provider where the error_logs are stored. But in PHP, just put this error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your page, you should see whats wrong. ALso make it a practice to use try catch statements.

Comment: @Akin I found the error log in my directory and It has the error undefined index phone, password(as i am passing these two values from android).

Comment: @Akin I changed the code and now there is no error in the error log

Comment: it does not mean. Verify that the phone and password values are not empty

Comment: @Akin The variables are not empty. Because i declared it manually as $phone=994******; and  $password= 1111;

Comment: @Akin How can i check curl is supporting or not in my server?

Comment: do this: $ch = curl_init();  if($ch === false) { die('CURL is not supprted');  }

Comment: @Akin CURL is supporting in my server.

Comment: @Akin I Used file_get_contents($smslink); now its working. Is it a good way to use this method?